# Android chatbot Gui link with Program Ab AIML interpreter

Tags: java, android, chatbot, aiml

I'm developing an android chat bot app with program AB that is an AIML java interpreter.
 I need some help to make the Android GUI that access the AIML files and gives the answer back. 
I already created an Chat GUI in Android, it is a scrollable list with adapter, that can hold the messages(requests and answers).
The app works. It can send requests and get answers but I don't know how to show this messages in TextView from ListView.

This is how my Android Chat code looks:
 http://javapapers.com/android/android-chat-bubble/

To implement the aiml files with Program AB that links the Bot with Android, I used this model:
https://github.com/bradleybossard/android-program-ab-demo

Comment: This is the one I used for my reference too. In my case the app just crashes. Doesnt work.

Answer (score 1):

Since I have tried this solution and in my case in my android 6 version none of the text display methods worked I wouldnt wanna discuss about it but in case the setText() is not looking fruitful (maybe a UI freeze) try

```
 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),yourmessageString,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

This will generate a toast that would be an alternate to display your message.